# How to encode a JPG image in a PostgreSQL database from BYTEA

Tags: xml, postgresql

So I have some JPG images stored in a `BYTEA` column in a PostgreSQL database table. I want to extract the binary and drop it into an `<img\>` tag. Here's the first bit of one of those files...

```
mydb=# SELECT LEFT(encode(image_file, 'escape'), 80) FROM image_files WHERE id = '53';                                                                         
                                       left
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 x/ffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100010000ffdb004300100b0c0e0c0a100e0d0e12111013
(1 row)
```

This binary data pretty well matches what I can see in the actual image file (using Vim's 'Convert to HEX')...

[image]

But when I try to encode it to `base64` (so I can use the data via XSLT to include in a web page) it appears to get corrupted. Here's a snippet from my query...

```
xmlelement(NAME "pictures",
    xmlagg(
        xmlelement(NAME "src", CONCAT('data:image/jpg;base64,', encode(image_file, 'base64')))
    )
)
```

In the HTML, I see...

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,eC9mZmQ4ZmZlMDAwMTA0YTQ2NDk0NjAwMDEwMTAwMDAwMTAwMDEwMDAwZmZkYjAwNDMwMDEwMGIw+
YzB..."/>
```

... instead of seeing what I'd expect...

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERAT..."/>
```

I somehow discovered (I can't remember how!) that, if I replace the 'x/' from above with '\x' at the beginning, I get the string I'm expecting...

```
mydb=# SELECT encode('\xffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100010000ffdb004300100b0c0e0c0a100e0d0e12111013', 'base64');  
                        encode
------------------------------------------------------
 /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERAT
(1 row)
```

So I'm left wondering if, when PG is trying to encode the hex byte array to `base64`, it's maybe also seeing the "`x/`" in the byte array and that's throwing it off? But I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to correct this in the query.

I'm sure this is an everyday thing and shouldn't have left me scratching my head for almost a week now! If I've missed off anything or there's any version info which is required, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever saved your files into the database in the first place screwed them up.  They might  be saved in a bytea column, but it is really text data storing hex digits, with the 2 literal characters `x` and `/` uselessly and misleadingly added to the front.  So something hex encoded the binary, but then stored the hex encoded string as if it were still binary.

You would need to chop off the first 2 bytes then cast the resulting string back from bytea into text.  Then convert the text holding the hex digits into real binary, and back to base64.

```
SELECT encode(decode(substring(image_file,3)::text,'hex'),'base64') FROM image_file WHERE id = whatever;
```

(You could actually do the cast to text before the substring, as well)

But rather than doing this conversion each time, you should probably refactor your table to hold more sensible data.  "More sensible" would mean either bytea data stored in a bytea column, or (if you exclusively want to deal with base64) base64 data stored in a text column.

Comment: Now that sounds like a very plausible explanation.  Thank you very much indeed!  I've been staring at this issue for prolly over a week now and this is honestly the first bit of common sense I've seen or heard!

Comment: I'll have a nice, gentle word in the morning with the chap who's supying me with the images to suggest he applies a little less engineering to the data...

Comment: I'm getting the following error from the `decode()`: `ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal digit: "\"
SQL state: 22023`. Any clue?

Comment: I've got there! The required conversion is `encode(CONCAT('\x', substring(encode(image_file, 'escape'), 3))::BYTEA, 'base64')`. Awful, but it works for now, until the other guy's got his end sorted. Thanks again for setting me in the right direction.

Comment: It looks like not all your rows follow the same pattern.  Could you show the specific value that caused that?